Why Component Destruction Occurs Before canDeactivate Guard : Component is destory before going to canDeactivate guard
I’m attempting to add an unsaved popup modal in my component. I’ve used lazy loading to load modules, and after that, I’m loading standalone components. However, I’ve encountered an issue: when applying a canDeactivate Guard, the canDeactivateFn loses the component reference. As a result, the component is destroyed before the canDeactivate Guard is called with a null component value. Is there any way to handle this? I’ve tried various approaches.
or is there anyone faced same problem in angular latest version?
Please guide me.
Thanks
i'm using "@angular/router": "^17.0.7",



reference: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/55867
i try to move canDeactivate Guard to different routing levels (app routing and module level).
also i try to manage this on global state but my component in refresh every time i switch to other module and then calling canDeactivate Guard.

please reproduce the issue in the stackblitz and update on the question, currently there is not enough code to even debug!

When you implement something like this, prefer the default browser alert window, since that will block refresh!
